# Trying to use SQL and discord.py to make a warn command that can show how many times a user has been warned

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

so this is the code i have so far

```
 @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True) 
    async def warn(self,ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        warn2= discord.Embed(title="Warning",description=(f'{user.mention} You are being warned for: {reason}'), color=0xEEA1FF)
        await ctx.send(embed=warn2)
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT warn_counter FROM warned_info WHERE user = {user.id}")
        num=cursor.fetchone()[0]
        print(num)
        if num is not None:
            cursor.execute(f"UPDATE warned_info  SET warn_counter = {num + 1} WHERE user = {user.id} ")
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

when i warn a user(that has been warned before) it will add the amount of warns to the sql code but if i try to warn a user that hasnt been warned before it wont add the user and add the amount of warns

[this is an  image of my sqlite table](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/799253205808316446/820121203942490152/sqltable.PNG)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is SQL can't update a record that doesn't exist. Users that have been warned already have a record, so you can update it. I'd add an else statement to `if num is not None` to create a record for those who haven't been warned yet, like this:

```
if num is not None:
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE warned_info  SET warn_counter = {num + 1} WHERE user = {user.id} ")
else:
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO warned_info (user, warn_counter) VALUES ({user.id},{1})")
```

Now if the user exists their warn counter is incremented, otherwise it creates a record with a warn counter of 1.

Comment: Instead if i add the user to the table and set the warn number to 0  on the member join would that work?